# Make comma separate values with single column in mysql

Tags: mysql

Here is my table information

```
Id Name
1 aaa
1 bbb
2 ccc
2 ddd
```

Ids are the repeated one. Now I want the result like

```
1 aaa,bbb
2 ccc,ddd
```

How can I do that in Mysql ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
select id, group_concat(name) as names
from your_table
group by id
```